# display connected user after login

Tags: angularjs

would you please help me to update my controller to change the username when the user is logged in is changed.
the problem that I'm facing is that even after updating the user, the field username is always empty.
Would you please help me to fix that?
here is my controller

```
controller(
            "HomeController",
            function HomeController($scope, sessionService, accountService) {
                var loggedUSer = {};
                loggedUSer = accountService.getuser();
                if (angular.isDefined(loggedUSer))
                    $scope.username = loggedUSer.username;
                $scope.isLoggedIn = sessionService.isLoggedIn;
                $scope.logout = sessionService.logout;
            })
```

and the username is displayed here after calling the controller

```
<b>{{username}}</b>
```

When I load my web page the username field is empty and is always displayed empty even if the username is populated after user login. Ineed to change that to display the connected user.

below is the factory used to retrieve the user and login :

```
factory(
            'sessionService',
            function($http) {
                var session = {};
                session.login = function(data) {
                    return $http
                            .post(
                                    "/myapp/login",
                                    "username=" + data.username
                                            + "&password=" + data.password,
                                    {
                                        headers : {
                                            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                        }
                                    })
                            .then(
                                    session.LoggIn = function(data) {
                                        alert("login successful");
                                        localStorage.setItem("session", {});
                                        console
                                                .log(
                                                        "localStorage after login: ",
                                                        localStorage);
                                        console.log(
                                                "session after login: ",
                                                session);
                                        console.log("data after login: ",
                                                data);
                                    }, function(data) {
                                        alert("error logging in");
                                    });
                };
                session.logout = function() {
                    localStorage.removeItem("session");
                };
                session.isLoggedIn = function() {
                    return localStorage.getItem("session") !== null;
                };
                return session;
            })
```

and

```
factory(
            'accountService',
            function($resource, sessionService) {
                var service = {};
                service.register = function(account, profile, success,
                        failure) {
                    if (profile.id == 1) {
                        var Account = $resource("/myapp/rest/account");
                        Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
                    } else {
                        var Account = $resource("/myapp/rest/account/teacher");
                        Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
                    }
                };
                service.userExists = function(account, success, failure) {
                    var Account = $resource("/myapp/rest/account");
                    var data = Account.get({
                        username : account.username,
                        password : account.password
                    }, function() {
                        console.log("user details : ", data);
                        var accounts = data.username;
                        if (accounts && accounts.length !== 0) {
                            console
                                    .log("profile id :",
                                            data.userProfile.id);
                            service.data = data;                            
                            success(account);
                        } else {
                            failure();
                        }
                    }, failure);
                };
                service.getuser = function() {
                    if (service.data){
                        console.log (service.data);
                        return service.data;
                    }
                    else {
                        sessionService.logout();
                    }
                };
                return service;
            }).controller(
            "LoginController",
            function($scope, sessionService, accountService, $state) {
                $scope.login = function() {
                    accountService.userExists($scope.account, function(
                            account) {
                        sessionService.login($scope.account).then(
                                function() {
                                    $state.go("home");
                                });
                    }, function() {
                        alert("Error logging in user");
                    });
                };
            })
```

Comment: What if you initialize $scope.username with 'uninitialized'? Then you can pinpoint if it is rendering or model/data issue.
Maybe also add an else branch to the statement, setting to 'undefined', to check if the logic is executed.

Comment: Does the login happen after the controller has been created?

Comment: try with `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`. It will persists the username across the app.

Comment: @martinoss I didn't understand your question but the username is displayed after user login

Comment: @maddog using rootScope may cause security issue :( is there any way that force the controller to update the variable?

Comment: @Pieter21 Sorry but I don't see what you mean, in fact the problem that I'm facing is that $scope.username is always undefined even after logging the user, when I try console.log I got the correct username in the log but in the HTML the display did not change as if the username is always undefined, what I'm looking for is to force the display to be displayed and updated as the one displayed in the navigator log

Comment: there is `watch`. you can use `$emit/$broadcast`.

Comment: Can you tell/show some more about the login process and account service?

Comment: @martinoss I just updated my first post and added the factory used to get user details and login. the problem is that when the HTML tries to get the content of username when it loads, the username field is undefined and it keep displaying it as undefined even after the user login.

Comment: @maddog, I'll try it with watch and let you know, but do you have any example ?

Comment: sorry for delayed reply. please see if this helps. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#watch

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding an ng-show.
That way you can show the username if he's logged in or "log in" if he's not logged in.

```
<div ng-show="username!==undefined">
{{username}}
</div>
<div ng-show="username===undefined">
<a href="login.html">Log in</a>
</div>
```

It's just a workaround.